# Subgroup of lattice-ordered group

Tags: gr.group-theory, lattice-theory, ordered-groups

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a [lattice-ordered group](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lattice-ordered_group) $G$. Suppose that $H$ with the induced order is a lattice (but a priori not a sublattice), so that $H$ is a lattice-ordered group too. For $a, b\in H$, let $ c=\inf_H(a, b) \in H$ and let $d= \inf_G(a, b) \in G$. Is it necessary to be $c = d$ or not? In other words, is $H$ an l-subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Isn't it true by definition? A lattice ordered group is an algebra with 4 operations: $\cdot, ^{-1}, \wedge, \vee$, so a lattice ordered subgroup is a subalgebra with respect to these 4 operations.

Comment: Sometimes a lattice ordered group is defined as a partially ordered group were the partial order happens to be a lattice, i.e., any two elements have infimum and supremum.  In this case the answer to this question is not so obvious.


Comment: @ Mark Sapir and Stefan Geschke, Thanks. I am trying to show $c=d$ but still I am not

Comment: As I understand, @Rajnish asks about a subgroup (not a lattice subgroup) which happens to be a lattice w.r. to the induced partial order, but which is NOT a sublattice of the whole group because the lattice operations in the subgroup are not the same as in the whole group. There are other algebraic structures (instead of a group) where this kind of a situation is common.

Comment: @ Wlodzimierz Thank you very much. I am completely agree with the "a subgroup (not a lattice subgroup) which happens to be a lattice w.r. to the induced partial order". I am going to correct my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A counterexample (essentially from Bourbaki's *Algèbre* VI.1 Exercice 12 a)) is the following.

We furnish $\mathbb{Z}$ with its usual structure of ordered group and consider the product of ordered groups $G=\mathbb{Z}^3$. This is a lattice, and for $(x,y,z),(u,v,w)\in G$ we have $$\textstyle\sup_G((x,y,z),(u,v,w))=(\sup(x,u),\sup(y,v),\sup(z,w)).$$ Now we consider the subgroup $H=\{(x,y,z)\in G\mid z=x+y\}$ of $G$, furnished with its induced structure of ordered group. This is also a lattice, as one readily checks that for $(x,y,x+y),(u,v,u+v)\in H$ we have $$\textstyle\sup_H((x,y,x+y),(u,v,u+v))=(\sup(x,u),\sup(y,v),\sup(x,u)+\sup(y,v)).$$ However, since $$\textstyle\sup_G((0,1,1),(1,0,1))=(1,1,1)\neq(1,1,2)=\sup_H((0,1,1),(1,0,1))$$ we see that $H$ is *not* a sublattice of $G$.

Comment: @Fred, Thank you. I did not get the idea used for subgroup $H$. Why is that on third compoent $(x + y)\vee (u + v) = x\vee u  + y\vee u$.

Comment: Dear Rajnish, I do not understand your question. Please clarify.

Comment: @Fred,Thank you very much. I did not get the result of third component in this line $sup_{H}((x,y,x+y), (u,v, u + v)) = (sup(x,u), sup(y,v), sup(x,y) + sup(y,v))$. 

Comment: First, $\sup(x,u)+\sup(y,v)$ is greater than $x+y$ and than $u+v$. Second, if $(a,b,a+b)\in H$ is greater than $(x,y,x+y)$ and $(u,v,u+v)$, then $\sup(x,u)$ is smaller than $a$ and $\sup(y,v)$ is smaller than $b$. Hence, $\sup(x,u)+\sup(y,v)$ is smaller than $a+b$. This yields the claim. (Note that the third component needs to be the sum of the first and the second in order for the triple to be an element of $H$.)